# Dropbox Core API - connection impossible - Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have seen several posts about my issue, but the solutions given don't solve my trick.

I try to connect my app to Dropbox core API, but it's impossible I can't find out why this line

```
final static private AccessType ACCESS_TYPE = AccessType.APP_FOLDER;
```

makes crash my code. The content of logcat is below:

```
10-22 23:16:54.071: E/AndroidRuntime(17666): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 23:16:54.071: E/AndroidRuntime(17666): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
10-22 23:16:54.071: E/AndroidRuntime(17666):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-22 23:16:54.071: E/AndroidRuntime(17666):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
10-22 23:16:54.071: E/AndroidRuntime(17666):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
10-22 23:16:54.071: E/AndroidRuntime(17666):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2115)
10-22 23:16:54.071: E/AndroidRuntime(17666):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
10-22 23:16:54.071: E/AndroidRuntime(17666):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:155)
10-22 23:16:54.071: E/AndroidRuntime(17666):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1252)
10-22 23:16:54.071: E/AndroidRuntime(17666):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-22 23:16:54.071: E/AndroidRuntime(17666):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-22 23:16:54.071: E/AndroidRuntime(17666):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5096)
10-22 23:16:54.071: E/AndroidRuntime(17666):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 23:16:54.071: E/AndroidRuntime(17666):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-22 23:16:54.071: E/AndroidRuntime(17666):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-22 23:16:54.071: E/AndroidRuntime(17666):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-22 23:16:54.071: E/AndroidRuntime(17666):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 23:16:54.071: E/AndroidRuntime(17666): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.dropbox.client2.session.Session$AccessType
10-22 23:16:54.071: E/AndroidRuntime(17666):    at com.example.dvp_list7.ListingArticlesDropb.<clinit>(ListingArticlesDropb.java:22)
10-22 23:16:54.071: E/AndroidRuntime(17666):    ... 15 more
```

I give you the code of the activity:

```
public class ListingArticlesDropb extends Activity implements PersonneAdapterListener{


    static final int REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX = 0;  // This value is up to you


    final private String APP_KEY = *** APP_KEY  *** ;
    final private String APP_SECRET = *** APP_SECRET ***  ;
    final static private AccessType ACCESS_TYPE = AccessType.APP_FOLDER;

     // In the class declaration section:
    private DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDBApi;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_articles);


        /**
         * Get objects from the precedent activity
         */
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        final String extras = bundle.getString("Title");




        // And later in some initialization function:
        AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
        AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys, ACCESS_TYPE);
        mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);


        // MyActivity below should be your activity class name
        mDBApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(ListingArticlesDropb.this);
    }


    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mDBApi.getSession().authenticationSuccessful()) {
            try {
                // Required to complete auth, sets the access token on the session
                mDBApi.getSession().finishAuthentication();

                String accessToken = mDBApi.getSession().getOAuth2AccessToken();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.i("DbAuthLog", "Error authenticating", e);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Thank you for smart people able to help me.

**EDIT**

I add the content of my .classpath file to give more clue to the people who help me:

.classpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Android/Project Download/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1/lib/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Android/Project Download/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1/lib/bcprov-jdk16-146.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Android/Project Download/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Android/Project Download/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1/lib/httpclient-4.0.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Android/Project Download/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1/lib/json_simple-1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Android/Project Download/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1/lib/httpcore-4.0.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Android/Project Download/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1/lib/httpmime-4.0.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Can you show me what your .classpath file looks like?

Comment: Looks like you didn't include the API in your app. Edit your clathpath and make sure it's checked under the "Exported" tab in Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you both of you to help me! 
@Mickael Krause you can see my classpath on the following link [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s840cc4llyaqwrt/AAD_vHygWjS3X1DvxpTn-L3ha?dl=0).

Comment: @323go sorry I'm a newbie, so can you give me more details please?

Comment: Newbie or not, my advice was about navigating menus and settings.

Comment: I have followed what you mean as you will see through this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s840cc4llyaqwrt/AAD_vHygWjS3X1DvxpTn-L3ha?dl=0). All .jar files are well present. 
Then thanks for your help, but it would seem your advice doesn't fit my issue.